# when you create an object which has events, but isnt added to the page, it doesnt save handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a fiddle which creates a viewer for a set of data.  If you are looking at the javascript, it will look at 3 lines, if you search for **SEARCH_HERE**

```
$("body").append("TEMPLATE<hr />Maintaining Object").append($maintence);
//$("body").html($maintence);
//$("body").html($_table);
```

The fiddle is located at:  http://jsfiddle.net/fallenreaper/wFGW6/1/

The first one will show the TEMPLATE on the page and then adding new ITEMS will all have working events when doing

```
var $data = $_table.clone(true,true);
```

in the *addBlock()* function.

If you only uncomment the second line, it will JUST show the maintainer item.
When you add items  **[+]**, you will show the form, but the events would not be there.

I was thinking that since $_table is removed from the page, the events are not there any longer.  The 3rd line, pretty much reappends $_table to the document, and the events are not  there.

IS this suppose to be like this?  Should i instead just create a wrapper function which is executed inside of *addBlock()* to attach all the handlers accordingly?

This is rather odd.

**EDIT:**

One answer, pointed to delegated events, which seems like it could work.  There is an issue though that seems to set $(this) to a new object, the body tag, instead of the selected element.

inside of a click event would be redefined as:

```
$("body").on("click", $expander, function(){...});
//instead of:
//$expander.click(function(){...});
```

I was thinking to just do something like left-hand assignment, something like:

```
$(this) = $expander;
```

but according to a website, left-hand assignment doesnt work.  (http://hungred.com/how-to/tutorial-override-this-object-javascript/).  They did point me in a direction which would be VERY useful.

```
function example(eventHandler){
  ALL MY CODE.
}
$("body").on("click", $expander, function(event){
  example.call($expander, event);
});

Does this look feasible, or should i be planning another route?
```

Comment: I get an error, because you used `new Arrays();`. Anyways, if you're worried about events with dynamic elements, you can use event delegation - http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Comment: Well, since the object $_table is not in the document, the events would not be saved from what i was looking at.  If that WERE the case, it could be useful to store the Events in the MAINTANENCE object and then reference it as such.

Either way, i do not feel this would be a solid approach.  The TEMPLATE would no longer be a complete template, but instead a 2 part template to append the handlers, am i right?  Maybe i am missing something as to how delegated events would work in this case.  I guess i could just wrap all the functions and set them on addBlock() but it different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `.on()` to do some event delegation. Your code is too long for me to read and edit, but in a nutshell rather than having `$add.click(function() { ... })` you bind the event listener to the parent or body `$("body").on("click", ".addNew", function() { ... })`

Comment: MMM, im not every destroying the body tag or doing a replaceWith() sort of thing, so building it and storing the events on the BODY does sound a great idea.  Im going to take a quick look and see if that would resolve it.  If there are some sort of issues, ill make an edit accordingly

Comment: Do you know if you can do something like:  $("body").on("click",$expander, function(){...});  Or should i do some sort of repeatable class as a selector.  I mean, $expander = $(<a class='expandWrapper'/>); but i wasnt sure if i could just say $expander or if i should say  "a.expandWrapper"

Comment: It needs to be a selector `string`. So, most preferably a class, because you could have multiple instances. (`"a.expandWrapper"` should do)

Comment: BRILLIANT.  Gods are not born, they are made.  You have become a god to me. :)  THANKS!  WORKS LIKE A CHAMP.